# how to prove completeness of functional space of C([a,b],V) wiht any norm ? give me a hint!

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Q Let V be a complete normed vector space.
>
> (a) Let $(f_n)$be a cauchy sequence in $C([a,b],V)$. show that for each $x\in[a,b]$, $(f_n(x))$is cauchy, and so define the pointwise  limit $f(x) =\lim_{n\to >\infty}{f_n(x)}$
>
> (b) prove that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly.
>
> (c) prove that f is continuous, and deduce that $C([a,b],V)$ is complete.

I was stucked by problem above Q
, because any norm isn't given in $C([a,b],V)$.
I wander if it is fault of book. or can I Prove above problem for arbitrary norm in $C([a,b],V)$? if the norm is sup norm in $C([a,b],V)$, I might be able to solve this problem. please advise me ! I need your help. thank you

Comment: I guess you can assume the norm to be the sup norm $\| f\| = \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \|f(x)\|_V$.

Comment: Given b it seems clear that c intends for the sup norm to be used.

Comment: thank you!  I will try to solve this problem with sup norm!

Comment: The space C([a,b],V) is not complete under an arbitrary norm. For example, if V is the real line and the norm on C([a,b],V) is the $L^1$ norm it is not complete.

Comment: @Rama Murthy thank you for your help. I will check your advice